# I'm confused on POST with sites like this

Tags: python, python-requests

Alright so this site is only a example but I hope you get the general idea of what I'm confused on.

Here is the code I quickly wrote for the site:

```
payload = {'firstname': 'Ryanous', 'lastname': 'Smti','email': 'thingy7237@gmail.com', 'PASSWORD': 'yaya7893478934',}

r = requests.post(WHAT_URL??? , data = payload)
time.sleep(1.7834734)
print(r.content)
```

So lets say I'm trying to sign up here (https://reg.ebay.com/reg/PartialReg) with Python Requests. So when I look into the Network tab to see what happens when I sign up 3 things happen. When I type my first name and last name that I type what I type is sent to https://reg.ebay.com/reg/track . When I type my email it posts to https://reg.ebay.com/reg/track as well as https://reg.ebay.com/reg/ajax . When I type my password the network console shows that it POST's to only https://reg.ebay.com/reg/ajax . However when I POST to any of these url's it doesn't work. What is going on?

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the complete request sent to ebay intercepted with **fiddler**,

```
POST https://reg.ebay.com/reg/PartialReg HTTP/1.1
Host: reg.ebay.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 741
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Origin: https://reg.ebay.com
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.81 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Referer: https://reg.ebay.com/reg/PartialReg
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Cookie: aam_uuid=60231779855192746434487614328071690113; cid=o48ObOkRdLGL6CaS%231913659548; AMCV_A71B5B5B54F607AB0A4C98A2%40AdobeOrg=-1758798782%7CMCIDTS%7C17777%7CMCMID%7C60242666160665362384488940468295249468%7CMCAAMLH-1536475733%7C3%7CMCAAMB-1536475733%7CRKhpRz8krg2tLO6pguXWp5olkAcUniQYPHaMWWgdJ3xzPWQmdj0y%7CMCCIDH%7C-1206723612%7CMCOPTOUT-1535878133s%7CNONE%7CMCAID%7CNONE; npii=btguid/a9479d531640ad4ba1dfdf77fff991ba5d6cbc38^cguid/a947a4721640aa46a1733082f26b543a5d6cbc38^; JSESSIONID=1163EA25E5D28E6D3FEFE265DC42CA03; __gads=ID; BidWatchConf=CgADJACBbloHkOTYwNmFiNzhmMTM3NDBjNzgyY2I1ZmE4MTk2MjdiMDDXi0VO; ns1=BAQAAAWWsLakOAAaAAKUADV12Y+QxODE1MTcyNTc4LzA7ANgAWF12Y+RjODR8NjAxXjE1MzI2MjQwODExNDJeWldNM1pHSXROUT09XjFeM3wyfDV8NHw3fDExXjFeMl40XjNeMTJeMTJeMl4xXjFeMF4xXjBeMV42NDQyNDU5MDc1q4Mtw+9aMn7pnSq6mpxylOOxeMc*; dp1=bkms/in5f579764^u1f/ANUJ5d7663e4^u1p/ZWM3ZGItNQ**5d7663e4^bl/INen-US5f579764^expt/00015326240648785c4a9681^pbf/%235280000000e000e000008180c20000045d7663e4^; s=CgAD4ACBbloHkYmVjNDM4N2YxNjUwYWRhMWY1MTJhOGFiZmZmYTQ0NzW5qXev; nonsession=BAQAAAWWsLakOAAaAAJ0ACF12Y+QwMDAwMDAwMQFkAAJddmPkI2EACAAcW7y9ZDE1MzQzNTQ4MzN4MzMyNjQzNDYxOTEzeDB4Mk4AMwAJXXZj5DkwMDAxLFVTQQDLAAFblTdsOABAAAdddmPkZWM3ZGItNQAQAAdddmPkZWM3ZGItNQDKACBk+zHkYTk0NzlkNTMxNjQwYWQ0YmExZGZkZjc3ZmZmOTkxYmEABAAHXT6SeGVjN2RiLTUAnAA4XXZj5G5ZK3NIWjJQckJtZGo2d1ZuWStzRVoyUHJBMmRqNkFNa1llZ0Q1S0hwZ1NkajZ4OW5ZK3NlUT09eh5LsYJBoaoQK/KuV1EGI2Ak2B4*; ebay=%5Esbf%3D%23%5Ejs%3D1%5Epsi%3DAxDh%2FH1E*%5E; ds2=sotr/b7r1Uzzzzzzz^

isSug=false&countryId=1&userid=&ru=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ebay.com&firstname=Ryanous&lastname=Smti&email=thingy7237%40gmail.com&PASSWORD=yaya7893478934&checkbox-default=on&mblChk=0&promotion=true&iframeMigration1=true&mode=1&frmaction=submit&tagInfo=ht5%253DAQAAAWSqr7ETAAUxNjRkNzgyZjgyNi5hZDc4ZWEyLjNhOGMuZmZmZjc3Yjm7B%25252BT3Tthy8Kdb8nvEHRiRxsMukQ**%257Cht5new%253Dfalse%2526usid%253Dbec438aa1650ada1f517e302ffff91fc&hmvb=&isGuest=0&idlstate=&profilePicture=&agreement=Terms+and+conditions&signInUrl=https%253A%252F%252Fsignin.ebay.com%252Fws%252FeBayISAPI.dll%253FSignIn%2526regUrl%253Dhttps%25253A%25252F%25252Freg.ebay.com%25252Freg%25252FPartialReg&personalFlag=true&isMobilePhone=&_trksid=p2052190&ets=AQADAAAAEOLzuussjt0oS0JDE3e8D_o%0D%0A
```

From the above raw request you can see, that you need to POST all these values to `https://reg.ebay.com/reg/PartialReg`. Some of the keys in data dictionary can be extracted from ebay's html page source.

```
data = {
    "isSug": "false",
    "countryId": "1",
    "userid": "",
    "ru": "http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ebay.com",
    "firstname": "Ryanous",
    "lastname": "Smti",
    "email": "thingy7237%40gmail.com",
    "PASSWORD": "yaya7893478934",
    "checkbox-default": "on",
    "mblChk": "0",
    "promotion": "true",
    "iframeMigration1": "true",
    "mode": "1",
    "frmaction": "submit",
    "tagInfo": "ht5%253DAQAAAWSqr7ETAAUxNjRkNzgyZjgyNi5hZDc4ZWEyLjNhOGMuZmZmZjc3Yjm7B%25252BT3Tthy8Kdb8nvEHRiRxsMukQ**%257Cht5new%253Dfalse%2526usid%253Dbec438aa1650ada1f517e302ffff91fc",
    "hmvb": "",
    "isGuest": "0",
    "idlstate": "",
    "profilePicture": "",
    "agreement": "Terms+and+conditions",
    "signInUrl": "https%253A%252F%252Fsignin.ebay.com%252Fws%252FeBayISAPI.dll%253FSignIn%2526regUrl%253Dhttps%25253A%25252F%25252Freg.ebay.com%25252Freg%25252FPartialReg",
    "personalFlag": "true",
    "isMobilePhone": "",
    "_trksid": "p2052190",
    "ets": "AQADAAAAEOLzuussjt0oS0JDE3e8D_o%0D%0A",
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response/answer. What if I had to post this payload repeatedly? What information (other then first/last name, email) would have to change?

Comment: `tagInfo, ets, signInUrl`, just check for hidden input fields in the page source.

Comment: I'm trying to get the tag info using BS4. But in the source code I see no value for the tag info.